# SharePoint 2019 Search KQL Boolean Operator "AND" doesn't work, "+" works

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, 2019, kql, kql-query

On our SharePoint 2019 Server we have a KQL that searches the whole Tenant for specific documents, by querying Managed Properties, like so: `ContentType:MyContentType AND FileType:pdf`.

According to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference#using-multiple-property-restrictions-within-a-kql-query the following 2 queries are identical:

- `author:"John Smith" filetype:docx`
- `author:"John Smith" AND filetype:docx`

However, I've noticed that my KQL didn't return all the data (only 3 documents instead of ~180):

- `ContentType:MyContentType AND FileType:pdf` - returned 3 documents
- `ContentType:MyContentType FileType:pdf` - returned ~180 documents
- `ContentType:MyContentType +FileType:pdf` - returned ~180 documents
- (`ContentType:MyContentType + FileType:pdf`) - **doesn't work** notice the space after `+`

With the three queries above I found, that the KQL including `AND` doesn't work properly. It doesn't return all the elements. It almost seems as if it was looking for the term `and` in the documents, implicitly building a query like `ContentType:MyContentType "AND" FileType:pdf` (ContentType:MyContentType, content=`AND`, FileType:pdf).

Does anyone know why the query doesn't work when using the `AND` boolean operator?

Comment: Are you using quotation marks with MyContentType e.g. ContentType:"MyContentType" AND FileType:pdf ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't change anything. For me `ContentType:"MyContentType" AND FileType:"pdf"` is the same as `ContentType:MyContentType AND FileType:pdf`

Comment: the quotations around filetype don't appear to be needed

Comment: Why you want to use "AND" work in your KQL because by default if you don't provide anything between two filter conditions, it will be considered AND condition only. You only need to provide logical operator when you specially want to you OR or NOT.

Comment: I know that "AND" is the default. But shouldn't it still work if I specify the default?